# Simple Spark job take too long with too many tasks

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have an hortonworks hadoop cluster whith the folowing :

- **8cores and 16go of Ram** (Namenode, Application Master, nodemanager and spark master and worker).
- **4cores and 8go of Ram** (datanode, nodemanager and worker).
- **4cores and 4go of Ram** (datanode, nodemanager and worker).
- **4cores and 4go of Ram** (datanode, nodemanager and worker).

so i'm using the following configuration for spark:

```
pyspark --master yarn-client --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 5g --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 3
```

[Spark environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0YTC.jpg)  
[Spark Executors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHSKN.jpg)

and i have two dataframes stocked like spark Parquets (glob and ind):

- ind : 2.2 GB of data (24 Column   5 003 498 records)
- glob: 3.5 GB of data (53 Column 270 338 406 records)

[ind dataframe disque usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRBCH.jpg)  
[glob dataframe disque usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ripwx.jpg)

The 2 dataframes have partitions by year, month and day and have the same amount of years, months and days.

i'm runing a simple count job on the 2 dataframes.

the "ind" dataframe (little one) take 23 min.
and the big one "glob" dataframe takes 1.5 min.

[ind dataframe count job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZuFw.jpg) 
[ind dataframe job duration and tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2qL4.jpg)  
[glob dataframe count job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xow15.jpg)  
[glob dataframe job duration and tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzI3p.jpg)

i don't understand why the little one takes too long and has too many tasks.

i appreciate every little Help, Thanks you all

Comment: You should try using Spark 2 on your HDP cluster

Comment: Okey, i'll try it and return to you with the feedback, Thanks